# Internal Server Error from AWS lambda in python when returning empty body

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, internal-server-error

I am getting a `500 Internal Server Error` with the following code in an AWS Lambda function and I cannot figure out why. The python code runs fine locally without any exceptions.

```py
def lambda_handler (event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
        },
        "body": [],
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `body` **MUST BE A STRING**. Objects will not work.

The (very simple) solution that took me an hour or so to figure out:

```py
def lambda_handler (event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
        },
        "body": "[]",
    }
```